# how to detect blocked address from within php

Tags: php, javascript

so here is my problem; we are trying to setup the facebook like and twitter tweet button on our website but it is causing browsers to become unresponsive when facebook and twitter are blocked on their computers.
so what i would like to do is detect if facebook or twitter are blocked and then remove the buttons for those computers, while allowing all others to load them.

is this possible in php or in javascript?

i haven't been able to locate any information about testing if a link is blocked or not.

Comment: How would a server-side language know if a client-side computher's network is blocking a specific site? It doesn't make sense. You just need to set a timeout on those buttons.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could put two hidden images on you page and have then add the like-buttons on the fly.
Something like this should work:

```
<img style="display:none;"
  onload="user_can_access_facebook()"
  onerror="no_access_to_facebook()"
  src="http://static.ak.fbcdn.net/rsrc.php/v1/yp/r/kk8dc2UJYJ4.png" />
```

Where the javascript function `user_can_access_facebook()` should add the like-button to the DOM.

(*http://static.ak.fbcdn.net/rsrc.php/v1/yp/r/kk8dc2UJYJ4.png* is the url to the Facebook logo on the login page. This might not be a static link so you might need to find some other static resource to check against.)

For twitter you should do the same.

**Edit:**
I put together a small POC:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
      function user_can_access(sitename) {
        var siteDiv = document.getElementById(sitename + '_access');
        siteDiv.innerText = "You have access to " + sitename;
      }

      function no_access(sitename) {
        var siteDiv = document.getElementById(sitename + '_access');
        siteDiv.innerText = "You do NOT have access to " + sitename;
      }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <img src="http://static.ak.fbcdn.net/rsrc.php/v1/yp/r/kk8dc2UJYJ4.png"
      onload="user_can_access('Facebook')"
      onerror="no_access('Facebook')"
      style="display:none;" />
    <img src="http://support.twitter.com/images/twitter-logo-no-bird.png"
      onload="user_can_access('Twitter')"
      onerror="no_access('Twitter')"
      style="display:none;" />

    <div id="Facebook_access"></div>
    <div id="Twitter_access"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

To try it out locally just block access to the respective domain above (static.ak.fbcdn.net
 and support.twitter.com).
As stated before you might need to find some other resources that are static to check against. If the urls' to the images change on facebook and twitter then you must change it in your code aswell.

Answer (score 2):

You could try having Javascript load up an img or other resource from twitter/facebook and see if it actually loads, then have some AJAX tell your server that it's not working.

But as far as PHP is concerned, there's no way for it to tell what kind of connections the client machine is capable of making.

Answer (score 0):

To manage this in PHP you would need to first detect if they have access using the JavaScript image method on a loading page then do a javascript redirect

```
document.location="/index.php?TwitterBlocked=true";
```

Based on the get parameter you could then choose to embed the code to show the buttons.

However this whole approach is ugly. The button code provided by these social sites is used across the web and if you have them loading as the very last bit of JavaScript on document load then shouldn't have a performance hit to your site.