# How can you programmatically check if an iframe would be blocked by a site?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, security, iframe

I'm generating a bunch of iframes dynamically that load random websites, and I was wondering if there would be a way to programmatically check if iframing for a website were blocked so I can fall back to a thumbnail of the site instead. Is there a way to do this, and if so, how? (JQuery is preferred.)

Comment: Look at this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5825502/how-to-detect-blocked-address-from-within-php/5825702#5825702

Comment: cool but I'm looking for a jquery solution

Comment: Is this a real issue?  How would a website infer it's running within an iframe instead of within a browser window?

Comment: By checking to make sure `top == self`. Usually sites will try to break out of frames rather than failing to load, though.

Comment: @kindall I'm the one doing the framing, and I want to check if the sites that I am framing allow framing.

Comment: Ah, your terms are confusing. What you are trying to do is see if a web site is using frame busting, not blocking. Blocking is easy - if the site doesn't load, it's blocked (or not available or whatever). Preventing frame busting is difficult, you can set a confirm using *beforeunload*, but the user will get a prompt. Probably not what you want.

Comment: @RobG that sounds good. You should write an answer showing/explaining all of this in more detail. Even how to check if a site is blocked  :)

Comment: This was a great question, too bad it remains completely unanswered.

Answer (score 1):

A *very* quick and dirty method to bypass some iframing blocks would be to append the url with a free defferer, like http://anonym.to/?site.com, though I don't really recommend this in legitamite practice.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to detect and stop frame blocking short of disabling JavaScript. Check this out, this is a function I wrote in response to the coding horror post [We've been... Framed](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2009/06/we-done-been-framed.html)! Its purpose was basically, "We want to make it *impossible* to frame this site... the easiest way is to just take it out on the user. The framing site will find out soon enough and the use will likely blame them." (It is a bit on the evil side, which is why it was only written as a thought experiment... but it works)

```
// if this is a framed site
if( window[ [ "t", String.fromCharCode( 111 ), "p" ].join( "" ) ] != window ) 
   destroyTheBrowser(); // royally mess with the user.

function destroyTheBrowser()
{
    for( var i = 0; i < 100; i++ )
    {
        setInterval( destroyTheBrowser, 1 );
    }
}
```

Firefox and Safari crash after consuming an additional 300M memory (last benchmark). Chrome crashes the tab. IE cripples the entire operating system. Can anyone show me script which will prevent this anti-anti-framing script from really messing up the user's browser?

If you don't care about JS, just load it through AJAX into a div with overflow set to scroll.

Comment: uhhh, sorry but could you explain your answer? You want me to run an infinite loop to disable the iframed site's JS? I don't understand

Comment: That script will break all framing sites. It is specifically designed to crash any browser which even attempts to load the site into a frame. It does this by continuously spawning intervals in exponential numbers

Comment: right, but why would I want to do this? I'm the one that is framing other sites, and I want to check to see if the site that I am framing has framing disabled.

Comment: You wouldn't, but they might. And if you load them and they've done this you won't be able to detect it.

Comment: dam... wouldn't it make sense for websites to have some standardized way of letting requests know if the site is iframe friendly?

Comment: That's a good point (a really good one -- it would mean the browser could handle whether or not to allow framing), but W3 probably won't let that pass.

Comment: btw why don't you think they would pass that?

Comment: HTML 5 won't be approved until 2022. I doubt they'll think about adding in the meanwhile.

Comment: Hmm. Well I'm going to email the chairs of the W3C HTML group.

Comment: I would strongly not recommend that any web-master do this... people who are trying to discover your site/brand via iFrames will have negative feelings towards a crash when they were viewing you through a third party... Bad Branding

Comment: A better approach is to just redirect them to your actual sight, rather than crashing their browser...

Comment: @AlbertRenshaw I wouldn't either, and that answer isn't suggesting that you *could* do something, but rather that if you are trying to create a series of framed sites (as the OP requested), then someone can do that *to you*. And redirecting generally isn't effective (look at the link I provided).