# Removing fb like button when fb is blocked

Tags: php, yii

I need to remove fb like button from a website for the users who have facebook blocked(corporate offices,schools).The fb like button appears using mouseover event.How do I make changes here to remove fb like only for those users who have facebook blocked.

```
function fbLikeButton(fb_url, prod_no){
        if ($.browser.msie && $.browser.version <= 10) { 

        } else {
                var src_val = $('#fbIfrm'+prod_no).attr('src');
                if ((typeof src_val == 'undefined')) {
                    $('#fbIfrm'+prod_no).attr('src', fb_url);
```

used here

```
onmouseover="fbLikeButton('<?php echo $fb_url; ?>','<?php echo $prod_no; ?>')
```

Comment: This [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5825502/how-to-detect-blocked-address-from-within-php) may helps you.

Comment: did you tried any code

Comment: @rikesh I tried that code but I am a beginner so I dnt knw how to use it with mouseover event

Comment: @MazIqbal I tried the code rikesh has linked here..

Comment: Kindly post your complete relevant code in the question itself.

Comment: If you use the JS SDK method of embedding the like buttons, then they would not even be rendered in the first place … because the SDK is embedded from Facebook’s servers, so no access to Facebook means the SDK won’t be loaded.

Comment: yeah its not loaded but instead there is an error on the place where the like button is visible where facebook access is present.So it looks weird and I want to remove the error also.